# Using a variable in between ' 's

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I have a bash script with a line that was originally this

`convert '%d.jpg[1-300]' combined.pdf`

Uses convert from Imagemagick to strap a load of sequentially numbered jpgs in to a PDF.

I've written a basic script to accept user input for a changeable number of pages and tried to swap the 300 for a variable set by the user when the script runs using read -p to make this:

`convert '%d.jpg[1-$pages]' combined.pdf`

The rest of the script works fine but it fails on this line and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

I suspect its something to do with incorrect delimiters but I don't know the correct thing to look for.

Comment: Any chance to see what the files looks like? Better give us concrete examples, sample input, expected output

Comment: @GillesQuénot, see the *Filename References* section at https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#input for background.

Comment: @GillesQuénot the files are names 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg etc. etc. a bunch of A4 page scans. they used to be a fixed size per pdf. But that goal post has moved and its now required to be flexible amount of pages.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: This is also possible: `convert '%d.jpg[1-'"$pages"']' combined.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter expansion is not performed inside single-quotes. It is performed inside double quotes though, so:

```
convert "%d.jpg[1-$pages]" combined.pdf
```

In any case, you need some form of quoting as `[` is special in most shells as a glob operator (`fish` being a notable exception, but in `fish` (older versions anyway) it's `%` that's special), and in all Bourne-like shells except `zsh`, unquoted parameter expansion is subject to split+glob which we don't want here.

Comment: That appears to have got it. Thank you for enlightening me as to what filename globbing and glob operators are and do. Same for parameter expansion.